# Why an extra none type str is returning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here is my code in Python for returning a string in capitalized :

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys


def solve(s):
    name = list(s.split())

for i in range(len(name)):
    nparts = name[i].capitalize()
    return print (nparts, end = " ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    s = input()

    result = solve(s)

    fptr.write(result + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

When I run only the function then the result is ok, but when I try to write the result in a file then I get the error below :

```
fptr.write(result + '\n')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

By manually checking I found that when I am storing the result into the result variable it also gets an extra value "None". I have no idea why this is going on. Please help.

Comment: `solve(s)` returns `None`.

Comment: [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7129285/3890632)

Comment: Also, a loop with a return in the loop will only run once, and about `return print(..)`: choose one.

Comment: Please share an example input and the expecte output in the file

Comment: There is around 3 or 4 errors in your code, co you really should give example input and output or just EXPLAIN what you try to do

Answer (score -1):

Your `def solve(s):` function doesn't return anything so by default it returns `None`

Fix it to:

```
def solve(s):
    name = list(s.split())

    return name
```

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: This is your code man, I just showed you that your function doesn't return anything, you didn't `return` a result

Answer (score -1):

To capitalize each word a sentence :

- `split` it
- loop on it to `capitalize` each word
- `join` them by space

```py
import os

def solve(sentence):
    return " ".join(word.capitalize() for word in sentence.split())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input("Give a sentence: ")
    result = solve(s)
    with open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w') as fptr:
        fptr.write(result + '\n')
```

Answer (score -2):

When the programmer does not define functions to return anything, Python function by default return `None`. This is the thing that is happening in your program.

The function `solve` does not return anything and so returns None which gets stored in the variable `result` when the function is called

A change that you can make in your program is to return the name.

```
def solve(s):
    
    name = list(s.split())
    return name
```

Also, in your program, a `return` statement cannot be used within a `for` block.
Moreover, `name` is not defined in your `main` program. A tip to fix it would be to change the variable name from `name` to `result` in your for loop and place the for block after calling the function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    s = input()

    name = solve(s)
    for i in range(len(name)):
        nparts = name[i].capitalize()
        print (nparts, end = " ")

    fptr.write(name[0] + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: It seems you took some time to prepare this answer, give some details but ... that doesn't work, you keeo overwriting `nparts` and the capitalization is useless so. My advice : ALWAYS try the code you post as answer, I'm here for 4 years now, 32k reputation and I'm STILL trying ALL code I post as answer ;) my pycharm is always open, ready to test code